# Product Main price should not update on custom option selection

Tags: magento2, custom-options, pricing

I am using Mageworx advance custom option module. Right now everything working fine.

**Current Workflow:**

My custom options are basically have radio/checkbox options. If i select any option then product main price also updated based on selection.

**What i want:**

If any user click on the custom option, product price should remain same. It should not update.

Check this screenshot,

**Here main price is $249. If i select any option then it's price also add along with the main price. So i don't want to update main product price. It should display same $249.
Please let me know if you guys have any idea. Your help would be appreciated.**

[image]